# Change Splash Screen from Ionic Browser

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I am having the following splash screen when starting my app:

[image]

I've only run

`ionic cordova platform add browser`

`ionic cordova build browser`

my config.xml

```
<preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: its web app or mobile app ?

Comment: It's a webapp @CodeChanger

Comment: I ran into the same problem did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to change

> value='screen'

with your own image (like assets/logo.png) in the config.xml file.

You can also change defaults sizes :

```
<preference name="SplashScreenWidth" value="300" /> <!-- defaults to "170" --> 
<preference name="SplashScreenHeight" value="300" /> <!-- defaults to "200" -->
```

The documentation of the splashscreen plugin : https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen

Answer (score 1):

Yes, change

```
value='screen'
```

to

```
value='/assets/imgs/logo.png'.
```

If you want to edit splash picture, go to

```
plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/src/browser/SpalshScreenProxy.js.
```

There is a default route for splashscreen pic `/img/logo.png`, it's not functional.